# visual studio post build event run exe with arguments

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, post-build-event

I have c# command line application that I need to run right after it's compiled so for this purpose we have Post-build event command line in visual studio. I am trying to run it and provide command line arguments but it always fails and exits with code 3. Not sure what there reason. This is how I am running it

```
$(OutDir)PRG.CommandsGenerator.exe -cs $(SolutionDir)TTP\Commands.xml $(SolutionDir)TTP\NAPI.Generated.cs $(SolutionDir)Data\
```

where PRG.CommandsGenerator.exe name of my executable

-cs -command line option

$(SolutionDir)TTP\Commands.xml - file in src direcroty in TTP folder that has to be passed as argument

$(SolutionDir)TTP_NAPI.Generated.cs - file in src direcroty in TTP folder that has to be passed as argument

$(SolutionDir)Data\ - folder in src directory that has to be passed as argument

Am I doing anything wrong ?

Comment: You might have problems with spaces in the directory paths. Try to use quotes around the paths.

Answer (score 1):

Embedded space in any paths?  Try enclosing all path arguments in double quotes.  Also try echoing out your command to view/verify in the VS build output window.  You may also copy it from there and paste to the command line to validate.

Comment: there is no spaces, but I have tried to enclose everything with double quotas, still doesn't work